# Delay in screenshots and cursor issue on macOS after update?

Tags: macos, performance

I'm running 10.14.6 (18G6032) Mojave on my early 2015 MacBook Pro. There was some kind of software update in the past week, and I've noticed two issues since I updated that I suspect were due to the update.

1. The screenshot option <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> seems to now be delayed. By this, I mean when you press those four keys and release, you get this "target" looking symbol that shows up to select where you want to start the screenshot. This target used to pop up instantly, but now there seems to be a 1-second delay.
2. My mouse cursor seems to randomly disappear sometimes, especially when I go into full-screen mode on a video. The cursor still works, but I can't see it on the screen. I have to move the "invisible" cursor to the top left Apple logo and click on it, and that makes it reappear.

Has anyone experienced these issues?

Comment: You don't need control to make a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is if a process is taking too much CPU. Are you familiar with the Activity Monitor?

- [Activity Monitor User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac)

I like to give it a try and make sure you have a backup if you are quitting processes you don’t usually start yourself (like Chrome or Safari or FireFox) in case stopping the process interrupts some work it needs to do. It also prepares you if you decide to reinstall the OS. Sometimes an update doesn’t complete its steps to be ready to run properly and just reinstalling it sorts out a newly slow machine.

Comment: Yeah I've checked activity monitor and there's nothing unusual (I actually check this daily ever since I got this macbook 4+ years ago). But I'm confused what this has to do with the screenshot and cursor issue?